problems with dealing with node and roboflow
I am dealing with roboflow API, but I am dealing with a status 500, but I can't understand why this is happening, i could use this with python, so the api key is working
   const imagePath = join(__dirname, 'image.jpg');
   await writeFile(imagePath, imageFile.data, (err) => {
     if (err) throw err;
   });
   const image = fs.readFileSync(imagePath, {
     encoding: "base64"
   });
   const actualTime = moment();
   const busResponse = await axios({
     method: "POST",
     url: `${INFERENCE_API_URL}/vehicle-detection-bz0yu/4`,
     params: {
       api_key: INFERENCE_API_KEY
     },
     data: image, 
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     },
     timeout: 50000
   });```


Besides the 500 status try to log the response body to the console to see if there are any error messages and update your question accordingly so others can help answer.

I tried calling a model from node via this API with a base64 image and it worked. Why are you writing to disk then reading it right back? What is imageFile.data (and where does that come from)? My guess is that your image isn't valid image data.
